# is there anyway to convert PHP/LARAVEL code to an executable?

Tags: php, laravel, desktop-application

What i meant with executable, is the same web application could be installed locally on our client's machine, without leaving a chance for the client to access the source code, just like C++

i tried adding a google shortcut in the client's desktop, but it doesn't seem like a good choice

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept of a web application which is what php and laravel are used for developing.

Comment: web application needs a browser to to properly function, you'd need a webview wrapper if you want it to act as executable file, take a look at Electron or Tauri

Comment: You could instead set up a [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) so that your app is centrally hosted and doesn't have to be locally set up on every user's/client's web server.

Comment: The short answer is no. PHP does not compile, so the only way for you to prevent the user modifying code or viewing it is just hosting it yourself and not giving the end user acccess to it, like any web page/company (service) works nowadays, a SaaS solution

Comment: i got what you mean.
i guess i found a way, it just looks like it's not running on a browser while it actually does.
using a PHP Desktop project and it is an open source project founded by Czarek Tomczak : https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop

Comment: When you install this project you will find a "www" folder, there you should paste all your php folders and files after deleting the old existing ones.
and after that you could run the executable file which points to the www folder where ur project's files exist and it will run a desktop window with ur index view.

Comment: Note : you'll need to run Xampp or Laragon or any Appache/MySQL Server manager before, or simply just configure it to run on the start up automatically.

Comment: and the best thing is in the open source project there's a configuration json called "settings.son" file where you could parameter your app and customize how it will look like, like adding an icon,making it run fullscreen, disable and enable the maximin, close and hide buttons, changing the name etc..
and then u can add a shortcut on your desktop, but sadly the source code will still be accessible

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyHob.png)

i guess i found a way, it just looks like it's not running on a browser while it actually does. using a PHP Desktop project and it is an open source project founded by Czarek Tomczak : [enter link description here](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop).

When you install this project you will find a "**www**" folder, there you should paste all your php folders and files after deleting the old existing ones. and after that you could run the executable file called "**phpdesktop-chrome**" which points to the www folder where ur project's files exist and it will run a desktop window with ur index view.

**Note :** you'll need to run Xampp or Laragon or any Appache/MySQL Server manager before, or simply just configure it to run on the start up automatically.

the best thing is in the open source project there's a configuration json called "**settings.son**" file where you could parameter your app and customize how it will look like, like adding an icon,making it run fullscreen, disable and enable the maximin, close and hide buttons, changing the name etc.. and then u can add a shortcut on your desktop, but sadly the source code will still be accessible
this is how the **settings.json** file looks like :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7tbG.png)